# Overloading slash operator to invoke custom object's methods

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, traits, mixins

I have created a class called `Rational` which is a simple abstraction over rational numbers. Its constructor takes two args which it stores as `numer` and `denom`. My goal is to be able to allow the user of the library to write any expression of form `x/y` (e.g (`2/3`, `3/1`) as well as expressions using rational numbers (`2/3 * 15/16 - 10/31`, etc) as usual, but *instead* of that expression being sent to the FPU for a quotient, I want the arguments to be fed to a fresh `Rational` instance which will be then returned. The methods and fields of `Rational` aren't important, except for its trivial `toString`:

```
override def toString : String = numer + "/" + denom
```

Based on a discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264658/scala-infix-notation), I created a simple trait `Rationalizer`:

```
trait Rationalizer {
  implicit class WrappedInt(val x: Int) {
    def / (y:Int): Rational = new Rational(x, y)
  }
}
```

and then I made a small `App` to test if `Rational::toString` was invoked when I tried to print `2/3`:

```
object Runner extends App with Rationalizer{
  println(2/3)
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the operator sticks to the interpretation of its operands as `Int`s and reports 0, the truncated result of `2/3`.

Of course, if I change the name of the operator re-defined in `Rationalizer` to something else, eg, `foo`:

```
trait Rationalizer {
  implicit class WrappedInt(val x: Int) {
    def foo (y:Int): Rational = new Rational(x, y)
  }
}
```

and make the corresponding change in my `Runner` instance:

```
object Runner extends App with Rationalizer {
  println(2 foo 3)
}
```

then `Rational::toString` is called just fine. Furthermore, in the first configuration (`/` instead of `foo`), explicitly making the left operand of `/` a `WrappedInt` instance and making the `Runner` call as follows:

```
object Runner extends App with Rationalizer{
  println(new WrappedInt(2) / 3)
}
```

**also** produces the desired result.
However, my goal is to have the very same operator, '/', respond in different ways based on whether the `Runner` mixes in `Rationalizer` or not (so, minimal source code change), so that I can compare accuracy of computations vs speed of computations and generate some graphs.

Any ideas about overloading `/` and mixing in that trait into my `Runner`?

Comment: If the compiler can't find the specified method (`/` or `foo`) for the given type (`Int` or `WrappedInt`) it will look to see if an implicit conversion can be made to resolve the problem. (That's one reason why using lots of implicits slows compilation.) The compiler will never choose an implicit conversion if it doesn't have to. `/` is a method on the `Int` class, which is `final`. I don't think it can be overridden.

Comment: Would making `foo` (or `:/` or whatever) "respond in different ways based on whether the Runner mixes in Rationalizer or not" be enough? As jwvh says, you really can't do that with `/` on `Int` in particulare.